# Wrong quotes handling in JMS Translation bundle

Tags: symfony, web, translation

Faced strange quote escaping in JMS Translation bundle (or I'm doing something wrong). The target text in xliff file is like `"quoted-text"`. On result web page it is shown like `&quot;quoted-text&quot;` because ampersand in html code is printed like `&amp;` instead of 'as is' - `&`. Seems like there is excess symbol escaping somewhere between xliff reading and html code generation. Could anybody suggest how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding `raw` filter to translated string in twig file, like:

```
{{ 'quoted.text' | trans | desc('text which translation has quotes') | raw }}
```